# Private field of an inner class which extends another inner class in another package using reflection (package java.lang.reflect)?

Tags: java, reflection, package, inner-classes

How can I access a private field of an inner class in another package which extends another inner class in yet another package by using reflection (package java.lang.reflect)?

```
package MainPackage;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

class PrimaryClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        AuxiliaryPackage.TerciaryClass.BugattiVeyron bugattiVeyron = 
            (new AuxiliaryPackage.TerciaryClass()).new BugattiVeyron(
                new MainPackage.SecondaryClass());        

        System.out.println("Name: "+ bugattiVeyron.name);
        System.out.println("Tires type: " + bugattiVeyron.tiresType);
        try
        {
            Class bugattiVeyronClass = bugattiVeyron.getClass();
            Field invisibleField1 = bugattiVeyronClass.getDeclaredField("topSpeed");
            invisibleField1.setAccessible(true);
            System.out.println(invisibleField1.get(bugattiVeyron));
            Field invisibleField2 = bugattiVeyronClass.getDeclaredField("tamperedOdometer");
            invisibleField2.setAccessible(true);
            System.out.println(invisibleField2.get(bugattiVeyron));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            /* I ALWAYS GET AN EXCEPTION !! */
            /* I need a change to be done IN the TRY block. */
            /* WHEN THE BugattiVeyron class DOES NOT EXTEND another inner class, NO EXCEPTION. */
            /* See at the end for a detail of the just mentioned case. */
            System.out.println("An exception has occurred.");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



package MainPackage;
public class SecondaryClass
{
    public class SportsCar
    {
        /* Public fields. Accesible from any package. */
        public String name = new String();

        /* Protected fields. Accesible from the same package and subclasses in any package */
        protected String tiresType = new String();

        /* Package fields. No explicit modifier. Accessible from the same package only. */
        int topSpeed; //km per hour

        /* Private fields. Accessible from the same class only. */
        private boolean tamperedOdometer;

        /* Default constructor */
        public SportsCar()
        {
            name = "Sports car";
            tiresType = "Race";
            topSpeed = 250;
            tamperedOdometer = false;
        }

        public SportsCar(String name, String tiresType, int topSpeed, boolean tamperedOdometer)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.tiresType = tiresType;
            this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
            this.tamperedOdometer = tamperedOdometer;
        }     
    }
}



package AuxiliaryPackage;
public class TerciaryClass
{
    public class BugattiVeyron extends MainPackage.SecondaryClass.SportsCar
    {
        /* Default constructor */
        public BugattiVeyron(MainPackage.SecondaryClass secondaryClass)
        {
            secondaryClass.super("Buggati Veyron", "Michelin Pilot Sport PS2 PAX", 431, false);
        }
    }
}
```

When the BugattiVeyron class does not extend anything (after a few changes in the code) I instantiate it like this:

```
AuxiliaryPackage.TerciaryClass.BugattiVeyron bugattiVeyron = (new
        AuxiliaryPackage.TerciaryClass()).new BugattiVeyron();
```

... and no exception rises... So what should I change in the try block to get things done well?

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT 1.
I didn't mean to yell. I thought that the intro might get lost because of the length of the post. I have included the stackTrace. I apologize. This is my second question.

Here is the first exception (The other one is similar):

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: topSpeed
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Unknown Source)
        at MainPackage.PrimaryClass.main(PrimaryClass.java:17)
```

The line 17 is:
    Field invisibleField1 = bugattiVeyronClass.getDeclaredField("topSpeed");

EDIT 2.
I know it does NOT look like a "good programming pattern". This is about a research on the limits of java.lang.reflect.

EDIT 3: THE ANSWER.
I want to thank all those who were kind and patient to me and, tried to provide answers. Finally, I got the solution from [vsb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315129/vsb). So, it took around an hour to get the answer since I posted the question. A record! My first question has not received any attention at all since March the 1st.

Comment: Edit your question and rewrite it without caps. No need to yell anyone here.

Comment: I'd say that the best answer is "You don't want to do that".

Comment: But if you really need to do this ... you should not be squashing the exception like that.  Print out the stacktrace and paste it into the question.

Comment: The O.O.P. Gods are weeping this day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works.

```
        Class bugattiVeyronClass = bugattiVeyron.getClass();
        Class sportsCarClass = bugattiVeyronClass.getSuperclass();
        Field invisibleField1 = sportsCarClass.getDeclaredField("topSpeed");
        Field invisibleField2 = sportsCarClass.getDeclaredField("tamperedOdometer");
```

BugattiVeyron class doesn't have these fields, they are from superclass and must be accessed correspondingly.

You can use following method to find field in the class hierarchy:

```
private static Field getDeclaredFieldInHierarchy(Class<?> clazz, String fieldName) {
    if (clazz == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        return clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        return getDeclaredFieldInHierarchy(clazz.getSuperclass(), fieldName);
    }
}
```

But please consider another way to solve your problem. It's very bad style and should only be used when absolutely necessary.

Comment: I know it is not GOOD programming practice. It is for research purposes. Thank you so much for your time and concern. I will try it and let you know. :-D

Comment: Thanks! Thanks! Thanks! Everything worked like a charm. And I thank you, too, for the function that you courteously have offered me. You made it look so so so simple. How did you learn this? It is in no book or tutorial I've read. THIS IS THE ANSWER!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. All this information is available in Javadoc (you can read it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html))

Answer (score 0):

`getDeclaredField` gives you fields in the exact class referred by your `Class` object, [as stated in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField%28java.lang.String%29). If the field is not *declared* in the subclass, you won't get it that way.

You probably want to use [getField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField%28java.lang.String%29) instead:

> The field to be reflected is determined by the algorithm that follows. Let C be the class represented by this object:
>
> 1. If C declares a public field with the name specified, that is the field to be reflected.
> 2. If no field was found in step 1 above, this algorithm is applied recursively to each direct superinterface of C. The direct superinterfaces are searched in the order they were declared.
> 3. If no field was found in steps 1 and 2 above, and C has a superclass S, then this algorithm is invoked recursively upon S. If C has no superclass, then a NoSuchFieldException is thrown.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering so kindly. I have to say I felt bad (sad?) for things like "The O.O.P. Gods are weeping this day". I tried that method too (I forgot to mention it) and got a similar exception.

Comment: But the algorithm for the method getField seems to forbid what I try to do here so, perhaps, the answers is IT IS NOT POSSIBLE TO DO THIS.